# How can I draw edges as an array?

Tags: javascript, three.js, edges

I have 3d model with tessellated geometry (I have array of vertexes and triangles) and I have also array of edges from original non-tessellated geometry. I can't find any tutorial/example with description how to display array of edges and documentation of Three.js is incomplete:

```
//
// Cube geometry
//
//   4+--------+7
//   /|       /|
// 5+--------+6|
//  | |      | |
//  |0+------|-+3
//  |/       |/
// 1+--------+2
//
var cube_vertices = [
    [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0],
    [ 1.0, -1.0, -1.0],
    [ 1.0,  1.0, -1.0],
    [-1.0,  1.0, -1.0],
    [-1.0, -1.0,  1.0],
    [ 1.0, -1.0,  1.0],
    [ 1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
    [-1.0,  1.0,  1.0]
];
var cube_edges = [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 0],
    [0, 4],
    [1, 5],
    [2, 6],
    [3, 7],
    [4, 5],
    [5, 6],
    [6, 7],
    [7, 0]
];
```

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

r75: The `THREE.LinePieces` option has been replaced by `THREE.LineSegments`.

```
var eGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( mesh.geometry );
var eMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff000, linewidth: 4 } );
var edges = new THREE.LineSegments( eGeometry , eMaterial );
mesh.add( edges );
```

Comment: Wrong variable name! Change `var edges = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );` to `var edges = new THREE.LineSegments( eGeometry , eMaterial );`

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, as of r72 there is the [EdgesGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/EdgesGeometry.js) and the EdgesHelper for showing edges.

Answer (score -1):

*Moving solution from the question to an answer*

> When you create lines or polyline with THREE.Line(geometry, material),
>   then you can use optional third parameter called type and one of type
>   is THREE.LinePieces and it does exactly, what I wanted. More
>   information can be found in Line() documentation. You can create many
>   disconnected lines with following code:
>
> ```
> var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
> var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
> for(var i = 0; i < cube_edges.length; i++) {
>     // Add first vertex of edge
>     geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(
>         cube_vertices[cube_edges[i][0]][0],
>         cube_vertices[cube_edges[i][0]][1],
>         cube_vertices[cube_edges[i][0]][2]
>         )
>     );
>     // Add second vertex of edge
>     geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(
>         cube_vertices[cube_edges[i][1]][0],
>         cube_vertices[cube_edges[i][1]][1],
>         cube_vertices[cube_edges[i][1]][2]
>         )
>     );
> }
> var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces);
> scene.add( line );
> ```
>
> Maybe it's not the cleanest solution, but it works.